# Pass a file download from protected route to browser

Tags: node.js, file, reactjs, express, download

I have a react frontend and a nodejs/express backend. The backend can serve files (downloads) via a protected route:

```
GET /api/file/:id
```

When the frontend wants to start a file download, it sends a request to this endpoint using this code (and the `Authorization` header is set with a valid `token`):

```
axios.get(`${apiURL}/file/${id}`)
  .then(file => {
   ...
  })
```

The backend responds with this code:

```
router.get('/file/:id', requireAuth, = (req, res, next) => {
  ... 
  res.set('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
  res.download(file.path, file.filename);
};);
```

This works fine: the download starts and the binary data is present in the `file` object of the `.then()` case of the `axios` call.

My question:

Instead of downloading the complete file I would like to pass the file to the browser BEFORE the file download starts, so that the browser handles the download like a usual browser-triggered-download, where the browser prompts wether it should download or display the file. How can this be done...?

---

The solution:

Thanks to @FakeRainBrigand tip I added token based authorization via request parameters to the route (using passport strategy):

```
const jwtOptions = {
  jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromExtractors([
    ExtractJwt.fromHeader('authorization'),
    ExtractJwt.fromUrlQueryParameter('token'),
  ]),
  secretOrKey: secretKey,
};
```

Now I can pass the download directly to the browser to handle it:

```
window.location.href = `${apiURL}/file/${_id}?token=${token}`;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Authorization header is going to cause issues here. You should use cookies, at least for this feature. Otherwise, you'll have to include a token in the URL.

The two solutions are `window.open` in response to an event, or navigating to the url (e.g. `location.href = '...'`).

At least in some browsers, they won't actually navigate when there's a file download, despite you changing the location.